# When does Navi to talk to me?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

*Note: I haven't played through the game so try not to spoil anything.*

I just started playing the game again, and though one big complaint was that she talked too much I actually like her.

So is Navi on a timer or how does it work? I know that there are some events where it'll triggers her "Listen!" option, but otherwise it seems random.

Comment: Navi always talks when you want her to shut up :p

Comment: The question's been answered well, so I'll just mention that I thought she was fine too, so it's good you didn't let the complaints keep you from liking her.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hit `up C` and she will talk to you when she has something to say. I think she has something to say in the following situations:

- you are locked on to an object/enemy
- asks you to listen to her. (The super annoying *Hey listen!*)
- she flies away and hovers over an object.
- a picture of navi appears next in your HUD by the `c` button controls

You can also play **saria's song** and decline to talk to saria. Navi then asks you if you want to talk to her.

Comment: See [this comment](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129968/when-does-navi-to-talk-to-me#comment177672_129970) please.

Comment: @Scootaloo I updated my answer, hopefully it is more correct now, it has been a while since I played through the game.

Answer (score 5):

Her *"Hey, listen!"* triggers simply come up every so often to make sure you're not lost.  Pressing **C-up** to speak to her then will give you a general hint about where to go or what to do next.

If you'd like the hint on-demand, you'll need to play [Saria's Song](http://zeldawiki.org/Saria%27s_Song) and decline when asked if you'd like to speak to Saria.  You'll then be given the option to speak to Navi.

You can also speak to her via **C-up** when targeting an enemy in order to get information about that enemy as well as hints to fighting it.

Comment: Fi does the same thing in Skyward Sword.  Gets a little annoying at times.

Comment: The Listen prompt is also triggered by several specific areas to give you hints

Comment: When I press **C-up** (the yellow button I think?) it just brings me into a first person view. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? I'm playing on a Nintendo 64, and my game is version 1.0.

Comment: [It says here](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Ocarina_of_Time/Controls) that **C-up** is for First-person view, and **Respond** to Navi. I think my only option is to play Saria's Song as suggested by Colin D.

Comment: C-up will talk to her *if she is currently bothering you*. Otherwise it's the first-person-view toggle.

Talking to her at other times requires playing Saria's Song and then answering "no" to "do you want to talk to Saria?"; she'll then ask "ok, do you want to talk to me then?"

Comment: I was misremembering.  Must be time to play OoT again...